# ARM LPC1751 pins configured as I/O

Tags: io, embedded, arm, microcontroller, pins

How can I configure one pin for input and another for the output?

If I am not wrong this could be done with GPIO registers that controlls device pins that are not connected to peripherical functions.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20378/arm-lpc1751-pins-configured-as-i-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in [UM10360.PDF](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10360.pdf), Chapter 9: GPIO. There you can find the description for the FIOxDIR direction registers, as well as the reigisters for querying, setting and clearing GPIO pins.

I also strongly recommend looking at the CMSIS Standard Peripherial Driver Library that NXP offers for 175x/176x, look in [microcontroller support](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/) documents. Edit: There are lots of sample code in this Library.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dwelch67

I have a number of lpc based examples.  You are looking for the IODIR register, depending on the port and flavor of LPC, there are now what they call fast I/O registers.  a one in a bit location means that pin is an output, a zero an input.